# How to implement template_preprocess_page and template_preprocess_taxonomy_term?

Tags: theming

I am trying to implement
[`template_preprocess_page`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) and [`template_preprocess_taxonomy_term`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/template_preprocess_taxonomy_term/7).

I implement them in my `template.php` file after having replaced `template` by my theme name, but the functions are not called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't need to change the name of the template.php file to the name of your template. it should stay the way it is.
here is a good free video from drupalize.me on how to get started with preprocessing:
[drupalize.me template.php](http://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-advanced-theming-drupal-7)

Comment: I meant I replaced  template_preprocess_page with  mytheme_preprocess_page

Comment: ah... i see. didn't really get it from the question.

Comment: the only obvious thing I could suggest to try is 'drush cc all' :) whenever i make changes to my template files I usually forget this small but required step